Confusion solving expression in MATLAB
My MATLAB code
clc;clear;close all
syms n z
x=n^2*heaviside(n);
X1=ztrans(x,z)
x1=iztrans(X1,n)
X2=ztrans(x1,z)
X2=simplify(X2)

I have read MATLAB documentation of simplifycommand and according to my understanding X1 is equal to X3 and X1 is simplified version of X3
https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify.html
When i use simplify command i get X1=X2
otherwise X1=(z*(z + 1))/(z - 1)^3 and  X2= (3*z)/(z - 1)^2 - (2*z)/(z - 1) + 2/(z - 1)^3 + 2
I have tried to solve and simplify on my copy but i am not getting (3*z)/(z - 1)^2 - (2*z)/(z - 1) + 2/(z - 1)^3 + 2 equal to (z*(z + 1))/(z - 1)^3 
When i solved on copy as shown in attached snap, i got numerator simplified to -3z^2+5z but i was expecting it to be z(z+1) just like MATLAB
Where i am wrong , please advise


On the third last line of your image, -2z*-2z=4z^2 not 4z.

Thanks for your response. But please also try to tell a little bit wether my understanding is correct"X1 is equal to X3 and X1 is simplified version of X3".  So i also get insight into"simplify" command

There is no X3 in your code. Also the sentence "X1 is equal to X3 and X1 is simplified version of X3" needs clarification.
